# How to disable temporary tables recreation in hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate 4 is creating the temporary tables every time i connect to the database,

```
Hibernate: create table HT_.....
```

is there a way to create them once time only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do understand the purpose, but the problem is in my case, when the user select the same DB, it takes 10 secondes to recreate all temporary tables, so here how to avoid that :
i add this part

```
if (e.toString().contains("already exists")) /********* temporary tables exists we should break ********/
    break;
```

to the Class org.hibernate.hql.spi.PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy

```
protected void exportTableDefinitions(
            List<Table> idTableDefinitions,
            JdbcServices jdbcServices,
            JdbcConnectionAccess connectionAccess,
            Mappings mappings,
            Mapping mapping) {
        try {
            Connection connection;
            try {
                connection = connectionAccess.obtainConnection();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                // assume this comes from org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl
                log.debug( "Unable to obtain JDBC connection; assuming ID tables already exist or wont be needed" );
                return;
            }

            try {
                // TODO: session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().getStatementPreparer().createStatement();
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                for ( Table idTableDefinition : idTableDefinitions ) {
                    if ( cleanUpTables ) {
                        if ( tableCleanUpDdl == null ) {
                            tableCleanUpDdl = new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                        tableCleanUpDdl.add( idTableDefinition.sqlDropString( jdbcServices.getDialect(), null, null  ) );
                    }
                    try {
                        final String sql = idTableDefinition.sqlCreateString( jdbcServices.getDialect(), mapping, null, null );
                        jdbcServices.getSqlStatementLogger().logStatement( sql );
                        // TODO: ResultSetExtractor
                        statement.execute( sql );
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e) {
if (e.toString().contains("already exists")) /********* temporary tables exists we should break ********/
    break;
                        log.debugf( "Error attempting to export id-table [%s] : %s", idTableDefinition.getName(), e.getMessage() );
                    }
                }

                // TODO
//              session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().release( statement );
                statement.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error( "Unable to use JDBC Connection to create Statement", e );
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    connectionAccess.releaseConnection( connection );
                }
                catch (SQLException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error( "Unable obtain JDBC Connection", e );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Someday before I am also searching for the same but not get success but I found [very nice article](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitableBulkOperations) which explains why this Hibernate Temporary tables are necessary which is we know very well, But after reading this its clear that it cannot be done. Whenever Bulk Operations is fired ORM framework will create it.

I don’t think there is a better solution than what Hibernate is offering here but I do think it is the wrong problem being solved in a clever way.

Comment: I do understand the purpose, but the problem is in my case, when the use select the same DB, it takes 10 secondes to create all temporary tables

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK Have you tried to create all that table manually and then select the same DB. Hibernate will check for temp. tables as its already created it will not create it again. It's just idea I have not tried this one.

Comment: i read, test and check the PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy class, and it doest test if tables are already created, the solution is to change the code as i mention below