# (Oracle + Hibernate): How to avoid temporary table creation during bulk operations?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a scenario where hibernate is trying to create temporary tables during bulk operations.

But, unfortunately, the user does not have privelege to create tables.

This is causing the application to crash.

I have tried to override a particular method in dialect:

```
@Override
public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
    return false;
}
```

But, still this does not work.

Do we have an option to suppress temporary table creation?

No, my problem is different, the ['duplicate' question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305356/how-to-disable-temporary-tables-recreation-in-hibernate-4) clearly says: "is there a way to create them once time only ?". In my case, I want to totally avoid creation of temporary tables. As the user is not having privelege to create tables on that schema at all. Only insert , delete or update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable temporary tables recreation in hibernate 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305356/how-to-disable-temporary-tables-recreation-in-hibernate-4)

Comment: no. it is not duplicate

Comment: Yes the nitty gritty details of the question might be a little different. However the basic idea from one of the answer is that; `its clear that it cannot be done. Whenever Bulk Operations is fired ORM framework will create it.` The articles https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/02/jpa-2-1-criteria-deleteupdate-temporary-tables-hibernate.html and http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/ and https://rrees.me/2012/12/12/hibernate-temporary-tables/ explains why they are necessary and will always be used when bulk ops are performed through hibernate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why hibernate generates 'T\_' prefix tableName during insert and delete operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609285/why-hibernate-generates-t-prefix-tablename-during-insert-and-delete-operation)